# What is the upper limit of Spaces in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

10.5 and 10.6 limited users to a maximum of 16 spaces. Since Lion's space interface is a single (presumably scrollable) row, is there an upper limit on the number of Spaces?

Yes, I find myself needing more than 16 Spaces, frequently.

Answer (score 1):

16 spaces is still the maximum. (Tested on 10.7)

Comment: Well, that sucks.

Comment: @Jacob Johnson: Spaces in Lion also behave differently, so I think your usage pattern would probably be different. I suggest trying it out on a Mac with Lion installed (at an Apple store is a good option).

Comment: This doesn't include fullscreen apps